# How to implement a generic component like facebook fullscreen imageview (with the effects)

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiimageview, fullscreen

I would like to implement a generic component to show pictures in full screen like facebook have.
When you click above the UIImageView the image should be centered and fit in the full screen.
Note the transition effect, scrolling, and buttons that appear when you tap on the fullscreenimage.
The iOS Deployment Tarjet is 6.1, so I can't use custom transitions. Also I'm using Nibs , not storyboard.

[image]

[image]